# Inserir um dado no banco de dados usando o PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario ="root";
$senha="";
$db="pdo";

$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost; dbname = pdo', $usuario,$senha);

$stmt = $conexao->prepare('INSERT INTO tabela_pdo(nome) VALUES(:nome)');
$stmt->execute( array(':nome' => 'Lucas') );
```

Não consigo encontrar o erro neste código, não está adicionando o dado. Por gentileza alguém poderia me dar alguma dica? Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Qual erro é retornado?

Comment: Nascimento, remova esses espaços, deixe assim `$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdo', $usuario,$senha);`, fora isso não vejo erro, aqui funciona, só remova os espaços no seu DSN. Se não for isso, provavelmente é a porta, vc precisa alterar a porta. Pra alterar a porta seria: `$conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;port=$port;dbname=$db", $usuario,$senha);`

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as **variáveis** em seu DSN, remova os espaços do tipo(`host      =     $servidor`) e defina a porta, mesmo se for a padrão que é 3306.

```
<?php

$servidor="localhost"; 
$usuario="root"; 
$senha=""; 
$db="pdo";
$port='3306';

$conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;port=$port;dbname=$db", $usuario,$senha);

$stmt = $conexao->prepare('INSERT INTO tabela_pdo(nome) VALUES(:nome)'); 

$stmt->execute( array(':nome' => 'Lucas') );
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas

Comment: @Nascimento se solucionou seu problema, só aceitar essa resposta como a correta. Abraço!